Forecasting Multiple Linear Regression Trends on Same Time Series Data Visualization
I am trying to establish two forecasting lines on the same data visualization in a PowerBI dashboard. I will provide two images in this post. Image A shows the data table that I imported into PowerBI from Excel. This data table holds the fake data that I would like to use in my forecasts. Image B shows the time scaled data visualization that I would like to overlay with linear regressions. I have tried to solve this problem in both DAX and m code but have found no success. I can post my DAX attempts, if requested. I just wanted to get a fresh perspective on the problem/solution space. Can someone help develop a DAX solution to overlay multiple linear regression models over the sums of spent and remaining for forecasting purposes?



Project
WBS
Job Order
Report Date
Planned
Spent
Remaining




A
1.2.3
12345
1/1/2023
$   50,000.00
$       6,000.00
$         44,000.00


B
1.2.4
12346
1/1/2023
$     45,000.00
$         4,000.00
$         41,000.00


C
1.2.5
12347
1/1/2023
$ 100,000.00
$     13,000.00
$         87,000.00


A
1.2.3
12345
2/1/2023
$     50,000.00
$         9,000.00
$         41,000.00


B
1.2.4
12346
2/1/2023
$   45,000.00
$       6,000.00
$         39,000.00


C
1.2.5
12347
2/1/2023
$ 100,000.00
$       19,500.00
$         80,500.00


A
1.2.3
12345
3/4/2023
$   50,000.00
$     13,500.00
$         36,500.00


B
1.2.4
12346
3/4/2023
$     45,000.00
$         9,000.00
$         36,000.00


C
1.2.5
12347
3/4/2023
$ 100,000.00
$     29,250.00
$         70,750.00


A
1.2.3
12345
4/4/2023
$     50,000.00
$       20,250.00
$         29,750.00


B
1.2.4
12346
4/4/2023
$   45,000.00
$     13,500.00
$         31,500.00


C
1.2.5
12347
4/4/2023
$ 100,000.00
$       43,875.00
$         56,125.00


A
1.2.3
12345
5/5/2023
$   50,000.00
$     30,375.00
$         19,625.00


B
1.2.4
12346
5/5/2023
$     45,000.00
$       20,250.00
$         24,750.00


C
1.2.5
12347
5/5/2023
$ 100,000.00
$     65,812.50
$         34,187.50




r.com/GOSl9.png

Is there some reason you posted your data as a screenshot instead of as a markdown table which can be easily copy/posted to use to test possible solutions?  Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?

@RonRosenfeld I apologize. I did not think of it. If I can add it retroactively, I will, Or, I can repost the question.

No need to post a new question. You can easily edit your question to add the data as a markdown table, perhaps using this Markdown Tables Generator or others on the internet.

Perhaps I misunderstood. Is this what you expect, with separate linear trend lines for each Spent and Remaining columns?

If so, after creating the line chart:

Select the analytics pane
Enable the trendline option
turn the combine series option to Off


I don't think you can obtain the values of m and b from the visualization directly.  But you can use the DAX LINESTX function to extract them from the data, or you can use a custome Power Query function.
For DAX, select New Table from the Calculations tab.
Enter this formula for the table, (where Table refers to your original data table above)
Stats = LINEST('Table'[Spent], 'Table'[Report Date])

This will generate a new table with a number of statistics for Spent. m = Slope1 and b = Intercept
For Remaining, make the obvious substitution.
So for m and b we show this:

Edit: Custom Power Query Function addedNote this is only for a simple linear regression
For a solution using M try this custom function:
The code returns a two element list with the first element being the slope m, and the second the intercept b
(x as list, y as list)=>

let
    tbl = Table.FromColumns({x,y},{"x","y"}),

//If you pass both lists as numbers, this next line is not necessary
    #"Date to Number" = Table.TransformColumns(tbl,{"x", each Number.From(_), type number}),


    #"X*Y" = Table.AddColumn(#"Date to Number","x*y", each[x] * [y], type number),
    #"X²" = Table.AddColumn(#"X*Y", "x²", each Number.Power([x],2), type number),
    #"Y²" = Table.AddColumn(#"X²","y²", each Number.Power([y],2),type number),
    N = Table.RowCount(#"Y²"),
    #"ΣX" = List.Sum(#"Y²"[x]),
    #"ΣY" = List.Sum(#"Y²"[y]),
    #"ΣX*Y" = List.Sum(#"Y²"[#"x*y"]),
    #"ΣX²" =List.Sum(#"Y²"[#"x²"]),
    #"ΣY²" = List.Sum(#"Y²"[#"y²"]),
    b = ((ΣY * #"ΣX²") - (ΣX * #"ΣX*Y"))  /  ((N * #"ΣX²") - (ΣX * ΣX)),
    m =  (N * #"ΣX*Y" - ΣX * ΣY) / (N * #"ΣX²" - (ΣX * ΣX))
in
    {m,b}

Given your original data, the above returns:


So I did try this and it was close. However, I would like to obtain the y = mx + b formulas to forecast when my remaining values over time will converge with 0. I was not able to figure out how to get the linear formula using native PowerBI functions. If you are able to get the formula of the lines in your answer above, I think that solves my problem.

@BP130 OK, I added some information on using DAX LINEST to obtain those coefficients. You could also use a custom Power Query function, but it seems you are more interested in a DAX solution.

can you provide the power query solution too? I failed to mention that I am working in a January 2021 version of powerBI. The LINEST function apparently does not exist in Version: 2.88.2361.0 64-bit (January 2021).

@BP130 Power Query Linear Regression function added.

I am still testing this on my end. Thank you for all the help. The linest function outputs slope as spend per day, correct? I was not sure of the time scale while using date values. If so, I think you have solved this problem. I will post follow-on questions to another thread. Please check them out if you are interested.

@BP130 Yes, it would be the same slope you would see on an Excel chart if you chose to view the formulas.
